# Get $request variable in route function - laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this route

```
Route::post('/unicorn',['as' => 'unicorn',function ()
{
    //Despite popular belief unicorns can be controlled
    $pony = $this->app->make('App\Http\Controllers\UnicornController')->saddle(); 
}]);
```

And I also have a good reason to be making the controller within the route function instead of just using `'uses' => 'UnicornController'`.

The issue arises from the fact that the `saddle()` function requires the request

```
public function saddle(Request $request){
    dd($request->input('type'));
}
```

So... how can I

**A.** ideally be able to access `$request` within the route function

or

**B.** Get `$this->app->make()` to inject the request like using `'uses' =>` does

**..?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just take the `Request` object as a parameter to your route function.

```
Route::post('/unicorn', ['as' => 'unicorn', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request);
}]);
```

Make sure to import the correct `Request` class.

Comment: And now when I try again, it works... odd... anyway, thanks :D